# pods in istio mesh crashes

Tags: ssl, handshake, istio

All my pods deployed in the istio mesh are crashing.
When the application(spring boot framework) starts it tries to connect to  an external https URL(spring cloud config server) and during that process the handshake fails and the application crashes. 
Is there a way we can make this SSL handshake happen similar to what we do in JVM like installing the certificate in the truststore.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Istio-enabled services are unable to access URLs outside of the cluster because the pod uses iptables to transparently redirect all outbound traffic to the sidecar proxy, which only handles intra-cluster destinations.

You have to enable access to external servers, see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/.